# Spring And Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I am new to Spring MVC and hibernate, I have two Entity `Category` and `Sub_Category`, `Sub_category` contains `Foreign Key(Category_id)` how can i insert value in `Sub_Category` only with the value of Foreign Key.
I my case values are inserting in `Sub_category` and as well creating new row in `Category` table and getting the value of that newly creating row id and saving in `Sub_Category` table but instead i want the value of already existed id value of `Category` table and store it in `sub_Category` Foreign Key column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your object is category

after saving it as

```
 category.save(); // after the database insertion
```

create another object of Sub_Category as

```
  if(category.save()){ // I assume, saved returns true on successful     insertion

  Sub_Category subCategory = new Sub_Category();
  subCategory.setCategory(category); // category that you saved above
  subCategory.save();
```